# MYSQL how to sum values only if there is record for the day otherwise not to return result

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on hotel reservation platform and am trying to check which hotels have entered price for each dates between customer's check-in and check-out dates. If a specific hotel has not entered price for a date - it has to be excluded from results. Also if the hotel has entered price for each date between the dates range but available room number is < 1 - it has to be excluded from the results.
For example if customer checks prices for period 2022-01-28 - 2022-02-01 hotel with id# 14 has to be excluded from results because he didn't entered price for 2022-01-31

This is what I have so far as query and php code:

```
$dates = dateRange_reservation($checkindate, $checkoutdate, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'Y-m-d' );
```

the above function returns array with all dates within range 2022-01-28 - 2022-02-01

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> string(10) "2022-01-28" 
[1]=> string(10) "2022-01-29" 
[2]=> string(10) "2022-01-30" 
[3]=> string(10) "2022-01-31" 
}

$datequery = '';
foreach($dates as $date){
$datequery.= ' and room_date = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($date).'"';
}
```

My query is:

```
select id, property_name, logo, your_property_type, 
(select count(rating) from user_rating where property_id = properties.id and approved = "1") as number_voted, 
(select sum(rating) from user_rating where property_id = properties.id and approved = "1") as user_rating, 
(select sum(room_price_1) from room_prices where property_id = properties.id and available_room_nbr >= 1 and room_date = "2022-01-28" and room_date = "2022-01-29" and room_date = "2022-01-30" and room_date = "2022-01-31" ) as base_price 
from properties
where property_city_id = "215"
```

The above query returns 2 hotels and NULL for base_price for both hotels which is not correct, as
Luxor Hotel must not be included in the results because he didn't entered price for 2022-01-31. For The other hotel I was expecting sum of 166 for all days..

Please show me the right way to achieve correct results!
Thank you in advance

[image: Tables structure]

Comment: Make your query a subquery and use a WHERE clause. e.g `SELECT * FROM (ORIGINAL_QUERY)tmp WHERE base_price IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton after I tested I got empty results, no results..

Comment: This is the query that I tested:
SELECT * FROM (select id, property_name, logo, your_property_type, 
(select count(rating) from user_rating where property_id = properties.id and approved = "1") as number_voted, 
(select sum(rating) from user_rating where property_id = properties.id and approved = "1") as user_rating, 
(select sum(room_price_1) from room_prices where property_id = properties.id and available_room_nbr >= 1 and room_date = "2022-01-28" and room_date = "2022-01-29" and room_date = "2022-01-30" and room_date = "2022-01-31" ) as base_price 
from properties

Comment: where property_city_id = "215"
) tmp WHERE base_price IS NOT NULL

Comment: In the query for base_price, you have room_date = "2022-01-28" and room_date = "2022-01-29" and room_date = "2022-01-30" and room_date = "2022-01-31". room_date can't be equal to multiple values at the same time. That's why you are getting NULL. If you want to see if room_date is in a range, try BETWEEN or comparison operators.

Comment: I see your point @Steve but in case I check in $dates array than I will get not full result.. I mean if the hotel doesn't have price for 2022-01-28 but for the rest it still will be in the results which is wrong..